# Excessive memory leaking

Tags: ios, objective-c, memory-leaks

I have been experiencing NSInlineData memory leaks from the code below (particularly the while loop at the bottom). Ive exhausted most memory management methods but can't seem to get around this one. The code below is apart of music streaming application.

```
-(void)readRingBufferDataBit

{



if (state == AS_STOPPED || forcedStop == YES)

{
    if(ringBufferReaderTimer) {
        [ringBufferReaderTimer invalidate];
        ringBufferReaderTimer = nil;

        NSLog(@"The timer has been invalidated");
    }

    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:playbackStoppedNotification object:self];

    return;
}

void *readPointer;


allBytesAvailable = [ringBuffer lengthAvailableToReadReturningPointer:&readPointer];


[self printState:state];

if (allBytesAvailable == 0) {


    gEmptyRingBufferCount++;

    if ((gEmptyRingBufferCount) >= 20 || ((stopReason == AS_INITIALIZED) && (PacketTypeEndOfSong) && gEmptyRingBufferCount >= 2)) {


        [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:playbackFinishedNotification object:self];
        state = AS_STOPPED;
        stopReason = AS_STOPPING_EOF;

    }


    return;
}



 NSData *ringBufferReadData = [NSData dataWithBytes:readPointer length:allBytesAvailable];

[ringBuffer didReadLength:allBytesAvailable];

UInt32 ringBufferReadDataOffset = 0;

while (ringBufferReadDataOffset < allBytesAvailable) {



    int packetBytesFilled = [[ringBufferReadData subdataWithRange:NSMakeRange(12 + ringBufferReadDataOffset, 4)] pm_int32AtOffset:0];



    int packetDescriptionsBytesFilled = [[ringBufferReadData subdataWithRange:NSMakeRange(16 + ringBufferReadDataOffset, 4)] pm_int32AtOffset:0];

    int offset = AUDIO_BUFFER_PACKET_HEADER_SIZE + ringBufferReadDataOffset;





     NSData *audioBufferData = [NSData dataWithBytesNoCopy:(char *)([ringBufferReadData bytes] + offset) length:packetBytesFilled freeWhenDone:NO];



    offset += packetBytesFilled;


    NSData *packetDescriptionsData = [NSData dataWithBytesNoCopy:([ringBufferReadData bytes] + offset) length:packetDescriptionsBytesFilled freeWhenDone:NO];



    UInt32 inNumberPackets = packetDescriptionsBytesFilled/AUDIO_STREAM_PACK_DESC_SIZE;


    AudioStreamPacketDescription *inPacketDescriptions = [self populatePacketDescriptionArray:packetDescriptionsData
                                        packetDescriptionNumber:inNumberPackets];


    [self handleAudioPackets:[audioBufferData bytes]
                 numberBytes:packetBytesFilled
               numberPackets:inNumberPackets
          packetDescriptions:inPacketDescriptions];


    ringBufferReadDataOffset += AUDIO_BUFFER_PACKET_HEADER_SIZE + packetBytesFilled + packetDescriptionsBytesFilled;


    free (inPacketDescriptions);


    packetDescriptionsData = NULL;
    audioBufferData = NULL;


       }


ringBufferReadData = NULL;

}
```

Comment: Keep in mind that without an autorelease range inside the loop you will build up copies of your NSData objects until the routine returns and reaches the run loop's autorelease range.

Answer (score 0):

This sample code does not seem to have any leaks. But I noticed that you do this:

```
AudioStreamPacketDescription *inPacketDescriptions = [self populatePacketDescriptionArray:packetDescriptionsData
                                        packetDescriptionNumber:inNumberPackets];
....
free (inPacketDescriptions);
```

Never do this. It is a very bad idea.

First: the method name `populatePacketDescriptionArray` doesn't make it clear that this method allocates memory.  Methods that allocate memory should be named with `alloc`, `copy`, or `new` in their names.  That way it is clear to the caller that the memory needs to be freed later on.

Second: Maybe you have leaks in another part of your code. It is easy to miss a call to free() or dealloc if you call the above method (or other badly named methods that allocate memory) elsewhere in your code.